# Moving items in public folders takes a long time

Tags: microsoft-outlook, public-folders

We have a public folder and a subfolder in that folder, both containing contacts. When we try to move that subfolder to within the superfolder it takes a long time (both in outlook 2003 and outlook 2007). Is there a way to speed that up? The folders are shared between about five people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the bottleneck - have you  monitored your exchange server during such an operation? Do you see lots of CPU usage or disk/network IO?

Comment: I haven't done that yet, I'll give that a try